# Mac creating simple dylib?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mono, xcode4, dylib

I need to create a dylib using XCode for my client. The dylib will have only two function start, and stop. The people i m making this for use mono and they will call this dylib.  How can I create this?
Thanks.

Comment: You might want to read [Apple’s Dynamic Library Programming Topics document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode has project templates for Cocoa, C++ and C dynamic libraries.  Just create one of these and add you functions to it.